# Installing gtk2hs on ubuntu

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, gtk2hs

I am trying to install gtk for Haskell on Ubuntu. I have already installed the Haskell platform.
When I run `cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools`, I get the following error:

> Resolving dependencies...
>
> Configuring Cabal-2.2.0.1...
>
> Failed to install Cabal-2.2.0.1
>
> Build log ( /home/vishad/.cabal/logs/Cabal-2.2.0.1.log ):
>
> cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>
> Cabal-2.2.0.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
>
> user error ('/usr/bin/ghc' exited with an error:
>
> /tmp/cabal-tmp-11425/Cabal-2.2.0.1/Distribution/Utils/IOData.hs:36:0:
>
> error: missing binary operator before token "("
>
> #if MIN_VERSION_bytestring(0,10,0)
>
> ^
>
> )
>
> gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.4.0 depends on Cabal-2.2.0.1 which failed to install.

I have already installed the dependencies using the following command :

```
   sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libcairo2-dev
```

Comment: Haskell platform is generally recommended against. Have you tried using stack or nix? Stack is the most recommended tool. Both will ensure these errors never happen.

Comment: I ran `stack install gtk2hs-buildtools` and got the following error:

> Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-11.6 from implicit global project's config file: /home/vishad/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Downloaded lts-11.6 build plan.    
AesonException "Invalid flag name: \"bytestring--lt-0_10_4\""

Comment: What stack version are you using ? I would recommend  you to upgrade to the latest one if you aren't using so.

Comment: For that matter, what version of ghc are you using to run into those sorts of issues? The particular problem only occurs with ghc < 8.0. You should be using a newer ghc: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4785